# Storing functions in array. Is it a good practice?

Tags: javascript

```
var sing = function(name) {
    console.log(name + " is SINGING");
}

var cry = function(name) {
    console.log(name + " is CRYING");
}

var list = [sing, cry];

for(var func of list) {
    func('foo');
}
```

This is exactly what I want in my code. But I am not sure if its a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var functionName = function(name, action) { 
console.log(name + " is "+ action ); 
}
functionName("Aditya", "Programing");
```

> Aditya,  I think you should choose this format. It is always good practice to keep a single function for similar kind of tasks to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in some situations, it is the preferable design to store functions in an array.

Imagine the following `EventEmitter` class. You can register event listeners using a method called `on` and dispatch an event using `emit`. The functions are stored in an array:

```js
var EventEmitter = function () {
  this._events = {};
};

EventEmitter.prototype.on = function (event, listener) {
  if (!this._events.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
    this._events[event] = []; // stores the listeners bound to the event's name
  }
  this._events[event].push(listener); // add the listener to the event's listeners array
};

EventEmitter.prototype.emit = function (event) {
  var args = Array.slice(arguments, 1);
  if (this._events.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
    this._events[event].forEach(function (listener) {
      listener.apply(null, args);
    });
  }
}

var emitter = new EventEmitter();

// push the first function to the array
emitter.on('event-a', function (data) {
  console.log('Event A was fired!');
});

// push the second function to the array
emitter.on('event-a', function (data) {
  console.log('Second listener to event A');
});

emitter.on('event-b', function (a, b, c) {
  console.log('Event B:', a + b + c);
});

emitter.emit('event-a');
setTimeout(function () {
  emitter.emit('event-b', 2, 3, 4);
}, 1500);
```

This is why I would use it in some situations. I don't consider it bad practice.